# Is it worth abstracting out Object creation for single classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I'm playing around with design patterns, and things are coming along nicely. One thing I'm unsure of is it worth abstracting out Object creation when there is currently only one object?

For example a project I'm working on contains two different user types which are not related in any way. They are IStudent and IStaff. For the application in question, there will never be any other types of user (staff Roles handle all none-student interactions with the system).

In my controllers I could simply:

```
IStudent student = new Student();
```

Or I something like this:

```
public static class UserFactory
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(IStudent))
            return new Student() as T;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(IStaff))
            return new Staff() as T;

         throw new Exception("The requested user type is not valid.");
    }
}
```

And then:

```
IStudent student = UserFactory.Create<IStudent>();
```

Is this overkill? I'm trying to work out best practice in these situations.

Comment: The answers seem pretty unanimous so far! I guess I was thinking about programming to interfaces, so removing *all* reference of concrete classes from the code. I wasn't sure how far one should take it.

Comment: Up to you of course, but I still say you're creating unnecessary work for yourself. Wait until coding to interfaces is the simplest solution to an actual problem, as opposed to "good programming style".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use TDD for most development. One thing I like about that is that it provides an answer for your question: "not unless it's required to make a failing unit test pass".

In other words, if you don't need it, then don't do it.

Comment: This post doesn't really address when/how to use the factory pattern.  It's more of a general platitude than anything else.  If the intent is to say "never use a factory pattern" then this post is horrible.  If the example in my answer were used with this method, you could end up with 15 branch if statements everywhere.  Passing a test is NOT synonymous with good programming style.

Comment: IMHO, "good programming style" doesn't imply using GOF design patterns just to say you read the book. Design Patterns should be used to solve common _problems_. If you don't need a factory pattern then you don't have a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's different from what I said... I pointed to a case where not refactoring i.e. doing *only* what is required to make the test pass, will cause significant maintenance issues in your code.  Obviously you shouldn't use a pattern that doesn't increase the maintainability of your code!

Comment: Your code doesn't need the "maintainability" until it needs to be  maintained. How will you test the factory code to make sure it meets your requirements? If your requirements don't include "use a factory always", then what requirements will you test against? Do your requirements (and standards are technical requirements) state that you must use a factory for all classes? If so, then of course you must use a factory, and you need one. Otherwise, you're wasting time producing unnecessary code because it is "good programming style".

Comment: I've worked on systems where that principle was in place.  10 years in and the maintenance was a nightmare.  Code was duplicated all over the place so much that a minor functional change could require code changes in 15 or more places instead of one if appropriate refactoring had been done.  It was almost impossible to tell if all needed changes had been done because nothing was ever refactored.

Comment: The "motto" of TDD is "Red, Green, Refactor". There would never be any duplication of code. If the refactoring led to the discovery that a factory would reduce duplication, then _that_ would be the time to introduce a factory - and rerun the tests.

Answer (score 4):

Ok ... you need a factory class, or just, you need to call the constructor.
Why people have fear to call a constructor?

I believe that patterns are good. I believe also that the abuse of them is pure evil :)

If you start to see that your programming paradigm is making your life harder, then abandon that paradigm, not your programmer abilities.
Sometime too much abstraction is just not useful at all.

Being clean and writing clean codes don't means following a pattern, means writing code that makes sense.

The Factory pattern: if we have to write a Factory for the Factory and a Factory for the Factory for the Factory .... until the deadline arrives, when we write the real code?

Since I see system analysts more as architects than bricklayers, i believe that just following some rule cannot make your software good.

People can blame Turing or Church or Goedel if they want, but is not their fault if a software that write software cannot be written :)
We still need our human part to write software, our creativity and imagination and our soul, also if some software engeneer tried to make it a pure mechanical act, programming is still an art in a big part of it.

Conclusion: I believe patterns are very good if used with the right criticism and following always the good programmer's sixth sense :)

I think that programming requires some flexibility, we are not in a perfect world, we have no perfect computer, we are not perfect and our software cannot be perfect and especially machine cannot think, still.

So, calling a constructor is always better than 2000 lines of code to just call a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, your solution provides no benefits over simply calling the constructor. If you have a reason for a factory, then by all means. Otherwise, don't over-complicate your code.

If your controller always knows what kind of User it's going to create (i.e. it's always going to pass in a concrete type in your type parameter), you don't need a factory.

Answer (score 2):

You would generally only use the factory pattern when creating more than one type and you want to hide creation to prevent ugly things like:

```
if(newPerson == "student")
 person = new Student();
else if(newPerson == "Staff")
 person = new Staff();
```

You could then just do:

```
Person.CreatePerson(newPerson);
```

Again, this only matters if you have to do if then statements in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your message:

```
there will never be any other types of user (staff Roles handle all none-student interactions with the system)
```

Very similar to this one:

```
640K of memory is all that anybody with a computer would ever need
```

In other words use simpler code you can, as suggests Sounders, but keep in mind that one day something could change, even if today it seems impossible.

**EDIT**

If you have a sequence of types (not just 2 ) of completely unrelated classes (from design perspective) Factory pattern applied by you could be pretty suitable IMHO.

Good luck.